# KineticJS stage getting cropped

Tags: javascript, css, html, kineticjs

I'm studying up on KineticJS and I've run into a question about placing the stage within a `<div>`.

I was playing around with [this example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-flower/):

[image]

When I reposition the stage using either `x`, `y`, or `offsetX`, `offsetY`, the stage gets cropped ([in my case](http://www.thepixelfarm.com/tmp/kinetic/interactiveFlower_mr.htm) the `y` causes the crop):

[image]

I've expanded the size of the `<div>` containers that house the stage, but that is not the answer.

Note that I commented out the inner div from the original file as it doesn't seem to affect the function of the page - the docs are a bit sparse and I want to learn how to use this tool as efficiently as possible.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Modify all the heights not onlye the #container height

Comment: There are only 2 containers, and they are both twice as tall as the stage.  Upon further testing, it appears that Kinetic JS is not very happy if the stage is a different size than the div that contains it.  Both changing the xy and changing width and height of the stage can cause the graphics to get cropped.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?  If you move the stage downwards, this is the expected behavior (you've moved the stage below the viewport)